# HttpActionContext not getting set with claims post AzureAD authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, asp.net-web-api2, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a web app developed using ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4.8) and ASP.NET WEB API 2 , SQL SERVER 2016. I am using Azure AD with OpenIDConnect (authorization code flow).

In this implementation there is a container web app (ASP.NET) which hosts the anguarjs (frontend) , web.config and associated bin and Global.asx file. Apart from it is also placeholder for API project containing all the APIs. The API project has its own separate web.config file and this API project is only used by the frontend web app. This web app uses Azure AD (OIDC) authorization code flow for authentication and has its own custom authorization.

Here goes the overall authentication flow:

[image]

The testapp is hosted as single site and the API project is hosted as application within the same site using IIS 10 as shown below:

[image]

The API project uses the same applicationpool as the testapp in this implementation.

There is one registration (overall the testpp and the API) in Azure AD. There is no separate registration for API project in Azure AD for this implementation.

Now on navigating to the URL: https://testapp.com I am redirected to Azure AD login page and then provide my details and signin and then can see the cookie and id_token getting set including the claims, but when there is a call made to the API in that case I see the context object not set and I see there are no claims maintained. I have  separate authentication and authorization filter at the API project level which gets triggered whenever any call is made to the webapis by the angularjs front end application. Also I see one more issue like if I navigate to the URL: https//testapp.com/services/api/test/method directly in the browser I don't get the Azure AD login flow getting triggered.

Here goes the Authentication and Authorization filters :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
      // Web API configuration and services
      config.Filters.Add(new TestAuthenticationAttribute());
      config.Filters.Add(new TestAuthorizationAttribute());
    }
}
```

TestAuthenticationAttribute.cs:

```
public class TestAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
 {
        private HttpAuthenticationContext _context;
        public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _context = context;
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(context.Result);
        }
    }
```

TestAuthorizationAttribute.cs:

```
public class TestAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            // retrieve principal and check authZ
            IPrincipal principal;
            if (!SecurityHelper.IsSecurityDisabled)
                principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as IClaimsPrincipal;
            else
                principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;
            if (principal != null && principal.Identity != null && principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "unauthorized");
            response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Federation", "permission required."));
            actionContext.Response = response;
        }
    }
```

In the above on debugging I see that HttpActionContext actionContext not getting set with any claims and hence no principal object is set and finally I see unauthorized response.

In case I try to access any other URL like https://testapp.com/test/app.js then I can see that Azure AD login flow gets triggered. Overall I can see calls to the API project are getting failed with HTTP status code: 401 (Unauthorized).

Calls to the API looks good in case of ADFS implementation. I am migrating the authentication module from ADFS to Azure AD and there I see the issues.

Can anyone help me here how to fix this issue.

Comment: I see that calls to api: https://www.testapp.com/services/api/test/method not at all triggering the Azure AD login flow. The APIs are hosted as application under the same site.